# Move column label outside (Horizontal Bar Chart)

Tags: jfreechart

[image: Barchart Image Link]

I need to move labels outside from bars, towards right. Image link is given above.

Bar chart label code:

```
BarRenderer br = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
br.setItemMargin(0);
br.setSeriesPaint(0, new java.awt.Color(227, 110, 37));
br.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
br.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);        
br.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.INSIDE3, TextAnchor.CENTER_RIGHT, TextAnchor.CENTER, 0.0));
```

Comment: What happens if you don't change the `ItemLabelPosition`?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=120393).